# is there a different algorithm for this process and what is the space complexity of mine

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a method that accepts an unarranged array of ints and return a boolean value.
my goal is to find if exists a unique number(meaning it does not repeat it self through out the array)
for example
{1,6,2,3,3,2,1}
the method will return true.(since 6 is unique)

my solution for this problem was to create two additional arrays in the size of the difference between the max value of the array and the min.
and than,iterate through the array,for each number we will increment the respective array place,if its positive it will go to the first array,negative to the second.

i claim that the space complexity for my solution is O(1) am i right?
(i speak about the worst case only)

and in addition can u show me a different approach to solve this question?
i am not allowed to used maps,Hash,lists or basically any other data structure that is not an array.

Comment: If input is of size N and range [0,N-1] (0, 1, 2, ...), you are creating at least one aux-array of size [0, N-1] -> N here, why would you think this is O(1). It's obviously aux-space in O(n). Why not use an approach based on sorting first (where you only need one loop after with O(1) space to check neighbors)?

Comment: well no, the aux array is not dependent on the size of the array. why would it be O(n) than?,more over i could have created two aux arrays in the size of MAX_INT, now would it make it O(n)?..i guess not,its still a constant number that isnt dependent on the input

Comment: You are wrong here. If you use a constant, it will constraint the content of the arrays to process (fail for huge numbers; i did not analyze your algorithm, but in this case your basic assumption is gone). If you need it to be of size [min,max] it's O(n) aux! It's dependent on the combination of size & statistics, but there is a worst-case like i showed.

Comment: why would it fail for huge numbers if i define constant MAX_INT..u can try it out..it compiles just fine,and please explain why is my assumption is gone. for the second thing u've wrote..i can agree with that

Comment: If your problem is undefined in regards to valid numbers, then also every number bigger than MAX_INT is possible. If you make your arrays MAX_INT, it can't be used if there is some MAX_INT +1 probably. But to make your algorithm work for every number, MAX_INT is actually non-constant and dependent on the stats of the input. So your little trick does not work in theory. Only if you are to design an algorithm for 32-bit int-ranges. **AlexP's answer emphasizes this**.

Comment: you're wrong,my "little trick" does work,since int array is limited to contain values of max and min depending on the language capacity and definition to int,it doesnt matter how large the array is.there is no MAX_INT+1

Comment: This is the wrong perspective in algorithm-design in general (at least in university-style algorithmic courses; not necessarily in real-world scenarios). It's all about the problem-definition. You got that assignment and you do have to interpret this algorithmic environment. Look at AlexP's answer which is explaining the same view and even describing the same algorithm i proposed/indicated. Already some upvotes, for a reason. But it's your decision what to do. We won't force you.

Comment: quicksorting and finding the value is trivial,i only wished to get more creative ways to solve this problem in (maybe) a more efficient way(in terms of space and time complexity).hope i wasnt too assertive,just trying to make my point here.thanks for your answers and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing now is histogram of array `a[n]` (with bucket sort) that is bounded to the dynamic range of the values `m = max(a[i])-min(a[i])`. If you do not know it you need to compute it which takes `O(n)` time (finding `min,max`). The histogram itself is `O(n)` time and `O(m)` space for bucket sort (not sure why you need 2 aux arrays). There are also other options:

1. **`O(1)` or `O(n)` space `O(n.log(n))` time**

   you can sort the array and then just find non repetitive value which is what **AlexP** suggest. If you can change the array you can sort in-place otherwise you need additional array.
2. **`O(1)` space `O(n^2)` time**

   test each number in array against all others and if no match found ...

We usually chose what we need at that time sometimes we need lower space other times time complexity.

For clever approach you need to exploit something like predetermined properties of the dataset. Do you have some knowledge about it apart that it has integer values (for example does it have Gaussian distribution)?

Another example would be if the data has small amount of distinct values (with respect to `m` so you got many repeating values) then dynamic list of values is better then bucket sort. That is `O(n.log(n))` time but the `m` in `O(m)` space complexity will be much lower as it will represent distinct values count instead of dynamic range.

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm uses unbounded space. (The auxiliary array can be made arbitrarily large for any input array containing at least two elements.)

My suggestion is to sort the array and find the first element in the sorted array which is different from both the previous and the next elements. (Sorting can be done in O(n) space and O(n*log(n)) time.)